# .net Maui - basic web request

Tags: android, .net, maui

Ive been playing with .net Maui and had some success doing Bluetooth LE but for reasons I've gone ahead and changed my implementation to use wifi and a restful API. I am building for both android and IoS. I am testing with a real device, running android 12.

I am trying to make a basic http(s) (tried both http and https) request to a local server (an esp32). My url is:

```
const string url = "https://192.168.4.1/api";
```

My manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="28" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

My initialisation function, which gets called when my page is loaded - MainPage()

```
private void init_network()
{
    client = new HttpClient();

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
}
```

and finally, my send function which gets called by a button pressed event

```
private bool SendCommand(string command)
{ 
    try
    {
        var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
        msg.Content = JsonContent.Create(command);
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.Send(msg); // line where the code throws exception

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I also have a runtime permissions section which asks for location_fine_access, which I've given access for.
When running through the request function, I get an exception thrown with the message:

```
[DOTNET] Operation is not supported on this platform.
```

I thought this was a permissions issue, and so android isn't letting me make the request but now I'm not so sure. Anyone else had and resolved this issue?

Comment: Can you see which line of code exactly triggers this error?

Comment: The url in your code is wrong. For android, the ip address always be 10.0.0.2 and also need a port number. So you can try to change the value of the url and try again.

Comment: Ive added a comment after the line which throws the exception above.

Ive tried changing the ip address and setting a port, but i totally disagree. The url is my TARGET web address, which is a static ip address I've set on my network. I can access the api from a browser, I cant access the api from my app because of the above error.

Comment: You can check the [official document](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking) about the IP address for the android simulator.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt specify that I am using a real device, not a simulator. I am using an android phone running android 12 (build tools 31), which I can access the webpage from a browser (chrome and firefox), so its not an address issue.

Comment: There is a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72313635/net-maui-android-cant-talk-to-api-localhost) which did the same thing and meet the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though .net maui doesnt hook into the android http client properly and is an issue on github. https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/1260
the suggested work around, which I have tested and works for me, is to instantiate your HttpClient with the native android handler like this as a workaround:

```
new HttpClient(new Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler()).
```